# Jquery Clone select not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my code of wordPress I am trying to clone `<select>` box with its options it works but the problem is all of  its option went outside ending select tag `</select>` I am not confirm whats wrong with it

Preview Image
[image]
HTML Output: https://jsfiddle.net/h5voq4nt/

PHP Code

```
$output .= '<label for="_jwppp-video-url-' . $number . '">';
$output .= '<strong>' . __( 'Media URL', 'jwppp' ) . '</strong>';
$output .= '<a class="question-mark" href="http://www.ilghera.com/support/topic/media-formats-supported/" title="More informations" target="_blank"><img class="question-mark" src="' . plugins_url('jw-player-7-for-wp-premium') . '/images/question-mark.png" /></a></th>';
$output .= '</label> ';
$output .= '<p>';
$output .= '<input type="text" id="_jwppp-video-url-' . $number . '" name="_jwppp-video-url-' . $number . '" style="margin-right:1rem;" placeholder="' . __('Video (YouTube or self-hosted), Audio or Playlist', 'jwppp') . '" ';
$output .= ($video_url != 1) ? 'value="' . esc_attr( $video_url ) . '" ' : 'value="" ';
$output .= 'size="60" />';

$output .= '<input type="text" name="_jwppp-' . $number . '-main-source-label" id ="_jwppp-' . $number . '-main-source-label" class="source-label-' . $number . '" style="margin-right:1rem;';
$output .= '" value="' . $main_source_label . '" placeholder="' . __('Label (HD, 720p, 360p)', 'jwppp') . '" size="30" />';

$output .= '<select style="margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0.8rem;" id="_jwppp-video-ad-' . $number . '" name="_jwppp-video-ad-' . $number . '" />';
$output .= '<option name="NoAds" value="NoAds"';
$output .= ($ads_client == 'NoAds') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
$output .= '>No Ads</option>';
$output .= '<option name="AdCode1" value="AdCode1"';
$output .= ($ads_client == 'AdCode1') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
$output .= '>Ad Code 1</option>';
$output .= '<option name="AdCode2" value="AdCode2"';
$output .= ($ads_client == 'AdCode2') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
$output .= '>Ad Code 2</option>';
$output .= '<option name="AdCode3" value="AdCode3"';
$output .= ($ads_client == 'AdCode3') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
$output .= '>Ad Code 3</option></select>';
```

JQuery Code

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var number = <?php echo $number; ?>;
        var $url = $('#_jwppp-video-url-' + number).val();
        var $ads = $('#_jwppp-video-ad-' + number).val();
        var $ext = $url.split('.').pop();
        var $arr = ['xml', 'feed', 'php', 'rss'];

        //CHANGE PLAYLIST-HOW-TO
        var tot = $('.jwppp-input-wrap:visible').length;
        if(tot > 1) {
            $('.playlist-how-to').show('slow');

            var string = [];
            $('.order:visible').each(function(i, el) {
                string.push($(el).html());  
            })
            $('.playlist-how-to code').html('[jw7-video n="' + string + '"]');
        } else {
            $('.playlist-how-to').hide();
        }

        $('.jwppp-more-options-' + number).hide();

        if($.inArray($ext, $arr)>-1) {
            $('.more-options-' + number).hide();
        };

        $('#_jwppp-video-url-' + number).on('change',function() {
            var $url = $('#_jwppp-video-url-' + number).val();
            var $ads = $('#_jwppp-video-ad-' + number).val();
            var $ext = $url.split('.').pop();
            var $arr = ['xml', 'feed', 'php', 'rss'];
            if($.inArray($ext, $arr)>-1) {
                $('.more-options-' + number).hide();
                $('.jwppp-more-options-' + number).hide();
            } else {
                $('.more-options-' + number).show();    
            }
        }); 
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: It could very well be a PHP problem, what have you done so far to identify and debug the problem?

Comment: I don't see any call to `clone()`.

Comment: @Zeus77 clone is through Jquery, i didn't get any error yet the problem is after clone the select field `<option>` tags show after ending `</select>` instead of before

Comment: Where are you cloning the `<select>` in the jQuery code you posted?

Comment: @Barmar see my updated question I have posted my php code too

Comment: $output .= '<select style="margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0.8rem;" id="_jwppp-video-ad-' . $number . '" name="_jwppp-video-ad-' . $number . '" />'; this has an end slash (/), remove it

Comment: @MirazChowdhury resolved my issue thanks can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes I have given the answer @Rtra

Comment: Done with your answer if you could recommend my question that would be great lot of people still looking for same question

Comment: The question says you're doing the cloning in jQuery, but it's actually doing it in PHP. It's a confusing question, and should not be recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP code has

```
$output .= '<select style="margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0.8rem;" id="_jwppp-video-ad-' . $number . '" name="_jwppp-video-ad-' . $number . '" />';
```

this has an end slash (/), please remove it.